# PHP Array rearrange numeric key as parrent key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to rearrange a simple multidimensional array.

```
Array
    (
        [pieces] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 9
            )
        [start] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0001
                [1] => 9901
            )
        [end] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0002
                [1] => 9909
            )
        [group] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0001-0100
                [1] => 9901-9999
            )
    )
```

to

```
Array
(
    [tokens] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Array
                (
                    [start] => 0001
                    [end] => 0002
                    [pieces] => 2
                    [group] => 0100
                )
            [1] =>  Array
                (
                    [start] => 9901
                    [end] => 9909
                    [pieces] => 9
                    [group] => 9901-9999
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried something similar this:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach ($keys as $key => $val) {       
    foreach ($array as $k => $v){
        foreach($array[$v] as $tk => $tv){
            if($val == $k){
                $new['tokens'][][$val] = $tv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The numeric is the set of tokens which i prosted from my form,

Please can anyone explain me what i do wrong?
I am working some hours with different codes (i know the solution is very simple) but I am a little bit confused :/

Thank you very much!

BR KK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourth Bird's solution is quite rigid in that it:

- Requires an explicitly-defined key in the loop condition.
- Enforces that the entire result has no more items than that one key has.
- Assumes and enforces that the input keys are sequential and zero-indexed.

The below will work no matter what:

```
foreach( $array as $y => $inner ) {
    foreach( $inner as $x => $value ) {
        $new['tokens'][$x][$y] = $value;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Rmdtd

---

**Edit:** I think it's worth preserving The Fourth Bird's explanation of the trouble with the posted code from his now-deleted answer:

> You are trying to index into `$array[$v]`, but `$v` in the case is one
>   of the sub arrays. According to the [array
>   docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):
>
> *Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in
>   a warning: Illegal offset type*.

Make sure that you have [`error_reporting`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned up to `E_ALL` while you're developing code so that you can see non-critical messages that indicate current and/or future problems.

Comment: thank you very much!
I am so stupid! at first i had the same iteration like yours but i tought i have to do something with "if"-statements and linked the fals vars to $new and was wondering why i do not get the result. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Thats better indeed! +1